# getting an error probably might be using older version syntax or something else

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
useEffect(()=>{
        return database.folders
        .where('parentId','==',folderId)
        .where('userId' , '==', currentUser.uid)
        .onSnapshot(snapshot =>{
            dispatch({
                type: ACTIONS.SET_CHILD_FOLDERS,
                payload: {childFolders: snapshot.docs.map(database.formatDoc)},
            })
        })
    },[folderId , currentUser])
```

I have written this code but i am getting error as :

> Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined
> FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Can you provide me with different syntax of handling compound where clauses and onSnapshot function ?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear: you're passing `undefined` as the value to one of the `where` condition, and that isn't allowed.

Either set a breakpoint on the line that causes the error and run in the debugger, or log the values to check which one is undefined:

```
console.log('folderId', folderId, 'currentUser.uid', currentUser.uid);
```